# Old JSON value Changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two JSON objects `columnsData` and `columns` when assigning `columnsData` value  to `columns` both values are changed.

```
var columnsData = [
      {id: "id"},      
      {id: "root_task_assignee"},
      {id: "root_task_id"},
      {id: "root_task_status"},
      {id: "root_task_tracker"},
      {id: "rt_category"},
      {id: "rt_priority"},
      {id: "rt_subject"},
]
var columns = [];
```

using the below function I  assigned the `columnsData` value to `columns` object, and also added some additional fields

```
for(i = 0;i < columnsData.length; i++){
    columns[i] = columnsData[i];
    columns[i]["name"] = columnsData[i]["name"] || columnsData[i]["id"];
    columns[i]["type"] = columnsData[i]["id"]["type"] || "string";
}
```

but after assigning both have the same values. How the old JSON columnsData value was changed? is there any other way to assign values

Comment: `columns[i] = columnsData[i];` does not create a **new** object. It merely assigns a reference to another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is required to keep original array pure (unchanged) we should use **map** method of array.

```
var columnsData = [
  {id: "id"},      
  {id: "root_task_assignee"},
  {id: "root_task_id"},
  {id: "root_task_status"},
  {id: "root_task_tracker"},
  {id: "rt_category"},
  {id: "rt_priority"},
  {id: "rt_subject"},
]

 var columns = columnsData.map(function(obj){ 
    var rObj = {};
    rObj[obj.key] = obj.value;
    rObj["name"] = obj.value;
    .....
    return rObj;
});
```

Logic can be added in map method to create new array as required. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`columns[i] = columnsData[i]` does not copy the data, it makes an additional reference to the same data.

For example, say you give Mr. Random Jones a nickname, "Cozy". If you give Cozy an envelope to hold, are you surprised if Mr. Jones is now holding an envelope too?

Same thing here. If you change `columns[i]`, you are also changing `columnsData[i]`, since they are the same object.

You would have to clone it if you wanted to have them be different. In this case, you just have to make a new object with `id`:

```
columns[i] = { id: columnsData[i].id };
```

In general, you would do well to find a nice `clone` function.

Answer (score 1):

> `columns[i] = columnsData[i]` will not copy content from one object to another but it will an reference of the `columnsData[i]`. As they are refereeing to same `object`, change in property of one object will affect the primary object which is being refereed.

Try this:

```js
var columnsData = [{
  id: "id"
}, {
  id: "root_task_assignee"
}, {
  id: "root_task_id"
}, {
  id: "root_task_status"
}, {
  id: "root_task_tracker"
}, {
  id: "rt_category"
}, {
  id: "rt_priority"
}, {
  id: "rt_subject"
}, ]
var columns = [];
for (i = 0; i < columnsData.length; i++) {
  var obj = {};
  obj["name"] = columnsData[i]["name"] || columnsData[i]["id"];
  obj["type"] = columnsData[i]["id"]["type"] || "string";
  columns.push(obj)
}
alert(JSON.stringify(columns));
alert(JSON.stringify(columnsData));
```